# WPF image memory leak

Tags: .net, wpf, image, memory-leaks, controls

I working on an application handling a lot of image files. I created a window containing a wrappanel that holds my images. The window takes a list of images (paths to the files) and creates a new image control which is then added to the wrappanel. When I open the window I see the memory usage going up, but when I close the window the memory usage does not go down. Here's what I tried to load the files into my image controls:

Using a filestream:

```
BitmapImage test = new BitmapImage();
using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(strThumbPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    test.BeginInit();
    test.StreamSource = stream;
    test.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
    test.EndInit();
}
test.Freeze();
Image.Source = test;
```

loading with a UriSource

```
var bitmap = new BitmapImage();
bitmap.BeginInit();
bitmap.UriSource = new Uri(strThumbPath);
bitmap.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
bitmap.EndInit();
bitmap.Freeze();
Image.Source = bitmap;
```

using a memorystream:

```
BitmapImage src = new BitmapImage();
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(strThumbPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    ms.SetLength(stream.Length);
    stream.Read(ms.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)stream.Length);
    ms.Flush();
    stream.Close();
    src.BeginInit();
    src.StreamSource = ms;
    src.EndInit();
    src.Freeze();
    ms.Close();
}
Image.Source = src;
```

I'm obviously doing something extremely stupid, can anyone enlighten me as to what it is?

Comment: you are forgetting garbage collection. try doing GC.Collect() before testing for memory footprint.

Comment: You should consider using a **virtualized** wrap pannel.

Comment: Forcing a garbage collection after the window closed does nothing. I'll look into the virtualized wrap panel.

Comment: Just tried virtualizing, but it does nothing to solve my memory problem. The images still seem to be kept in memory.

Comment: OK, I think I've found the source of the problem. I'm using Elysium to style my windows, if I remove it the memory gets released. Now to find out how to fix this without having to pass Elysium...

Comment: @Splatbang I've got the same problem, can you say more about Elysium?

Comment: I can't access this project just now, but if I remember correctly the solution was to dereference the window after closing it so the garbage collector cleans it up properly. Not sure how up-to-date this is though, I haven't touched this thing in ages. I hope I could help you :)